# defaultSourceDPIInt in the default theme.css of CodenameOne

Tags: codenameone

In the new Codename One bare-bones project (https://start.codenameone.com/), there is a default `theme.css` that starts with:

```
#Constants {
    includeNativeBool: true;
    defaultSourceDPIInt: "0";
}
```

What is `defaultSourceDPIInt: "0";`? I couldn't find anything in the blog about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's discussed here: https://www.reddit.com/r/cn1/comments/p0utte/defaultsourcedpiint_css_theme_constant_can_make/

> The `defaultSourceDPIInt` constant which you can use as:

```css
#Constants {
    /* ... */
     defaultSourceDPIInt: 0; 
}
```

> Sets the default DPI of images you use in the theme. This is very
> important as the default is the creation of multi images. With 0 we're
> essentially importing all images as regular images by default which
> means you need to explicitly state the source DPI to prevent mistakes.
> Check out the git commit for the full story:
> https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/commit/f31fb8a046759ed884ab61b2d34b42a614b2dbd2